# How to create a universal custom UINavigationBar back button without skewing the image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

So I am trying to set a universal back button image for every time the back arrow appears in the UINavigationController. However, every time I attempt to implement, the image gets skewed and extended. The original image is a simple back arrow. However, the back button image (that does work universally) is getting skewed as shown:

[image: UINavigationBar with Custom Back Button]

I have tried using the following code in my AppDelegate – still no luck.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    
    // Attempt 1
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
     setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"]
     forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    
    // Attempt 2
    UIImageView *buttonBack = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    buttonBack.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
     setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack.image
     forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the contentMode of the UIImageView of your back button.

Use this code to set the image to fit the UIImageView's frame and maintain it's aspect ratio of the image:

```
// Attempt 2
UIImageView *buttonBack = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
buttonBack.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];
// this line sets the aspect mode
buttonBack.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]
 setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack.image
 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Unfortunately still experiencing the same issue with your solution. Even tried setting the correct CGRectMake: `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)]` (16 x 16 is the icon size). Still appearing as it did in the original screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried setting the UIImageView as the customView of the UIBarButtonItem instead of the backgroundImage?

Comment: I attempted with the following code, but was faced with a crash error: **1.** `UIView *backButtonView;` **2.** `backButtonView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"]];` **3.** `[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setCustomView:backButtonView];` (numbers represent number lines)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a lot simpler than expected. Drop some of the additional code and trim it down to its barebones – you come out with something like this (in the AppDelegate, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions):

```
// Custom Back Button
UIImageView *buttonBack = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 16, 16)];
buttonBack.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Back"];
buttonBack.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```